# How to check if there is no value in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to create a randomizer for 3 digits in int arr[] and check the value of that. The value to be checked is if the array has a double, ex. (5,5,3) then it will get the  non repeating ex.(3). I used printRepeating to see if there is a repeating digit in the array and if there is, it will call the firstNonRepeating function to get the non repeated. The problem is in printRepeating, how do I check if arr[i] is empty or not so it will call the firstNonRepeating function whether it is not empty because even if it is empty(the array has no repeating digit), it still calls firstNonRepeating().

```
int firstNonRepeating(int arr[], int size)  
{ 
    cout << "\nvalue of roll is ";
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) { 
        int e; 
        for (e = 0; e < size; e++) 
            if (x != e && arr[x] == arr[e]) 
                break; 
        if (e == size) 
            return arr[x]; 
    } 
    return -1; 
} 

int printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{ 
    int i, j; 
    printf(" Repeating elements are "); 
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        for(j = i + 1; j < size; j++) 
        if(arr[i] == arr[j]) 
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
    if(arr[i] != 0)
    {
        cout << firstNonRepeating(arr, size); 
    }
}  


int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 5}; 
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  
    printRepeating(arr, arr_size); 
}
```

p.s. Also, is there anyway I can write a more efficient code for this?? I only borrowed other people's code for this...

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific use case there is nothing wrong with nested loops to match each element to every other element, checking for a duplicate. In an example with more digits there are a number of ways this may be determined depending on your constraints. The simplest is to create an `std::unordered_set<int>` and iterate over the array checking whether the current number is in the unordered_set and if not, add the number to the set and continue.
Example code for this would look like

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> getRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
    vector<int> rv;
    unordered_set<int> curr_set;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if(curr_set.find(arr[i]) != curr_set.end())
             rv.push_back(arr[i]);
        curr_set.insert(arr[i]);
    }
    return rv;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 5};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    vector<int> repeating = getRepeating(arr, arr_size);
    if(repeating.size() == 0)
        cout << "no repetition found" << endl;
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < repeating.size(); ++i)
            cout << i << "th repeating: " << repeating[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

where the return value of getRepeating would contain a vector of all repeating numbers